# Running graphical applications with pkexec

Tags: ubuntu

I want to run my GUI with pkexec.It works fine if I place `policy-kit` file in `/usr/share/policykit-1/actions` directory. I don't want to place any file in the `/usr/` folder as I don't want to write any content in that directory. Is it possible to envoke `pkexec` without placing a policy kit file in `/usr/share/policykit-1/actions` directory(and after that my gui should open after a successfull password attempt)? I want something like `sudo-prompt` [sudo-prompt](https://github.com/jorangreef/sudo-prompt).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [run part of code as root](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42779843/run-part-of-code-as-root)

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff `sudo-prompt` which is written in `JavaScript` runs without placing a policykit file.I want something like that.

Comment: I just took a look at sudo-prompt. It says in the README that it is specifically designed to run non-GUI apps. `pkexec` does exactly that. From what I understand you only have to put a .policy file if you want something more (like running a GUI app, which is discouraged anyway).

Comment: Is it possible to refork the same app after pkexec is executed? I mean if my output file has step1,step2 and if we envoke pkexec after step1,then in step2 it should run as root.Is this possible?

Comment: Once you are root "everything" is possible. It would be very complicated to achieve and is not recommended at all! Do not try something like that! Code running as root should be as minimal as possible and only as a last resort. In fact security experts advice dropping privileges in a root process: https://media.ccc.de/v/32c3-7284-check_your_privileges